# fprintf with string argument

Tags: c, string, printf

In order to create a formatted file, I want to utilize `fprintf`. It must get `char*` parameters, but I have several string variables. How can I use `fprintf`?

Comment: Can you post some sample code showing us what is the input and what is the expected output?

Comment: I have something like this:  

...  
string St1, St2;  
...  
ifstream In("Text.txt");  
In >> St1 >> St2;  
...  

that St1 and St2 are initialized by reading from a file by ifstream() function. Now I want to write them in another file by fprintf() function.  

fprintf("%s   %s", St1, St2);  

But I think fprint get char* not string.

Comment: The first argument for fprintf should be a FILE*, not a char *. In C there's no "string", only "char *".
Are you sure you didn't mean to tag this question with "c++" rather than "c" ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The basic usage of `fprintf` with strings looks like this:

```
char *str1, *str2, *str3;
FILE *f;
// ...

f = fopen("abc.txt", "w");
fprintf(f, "%s, %s\n", str1, str2);
fprintf(f, "more: %s\n", str3);
fclose(f);
```

You can add several strings by using several `%s` format specifiers and you can use repeated calls to `fprintf` to write the file incrementally.

If you have C++ `std::string` objects you can use their `c_str()` method to get a `const char*` suitable to use with `fprintf`:

```
std::string str("abc");
fprintf(f, "%s\n", str.c_str());
```

Answer (score 3):

fprintf with multiple strings is pretty simple, if that is what you are after, e.g.

```
const char* charString1 = "This";
const char* charString2 = "is a";
const char* charString3 = "test";

fprintf(fileHandle, "%s, %s, %s", charString1, charString2, charString3);
```

Comment: I have something like this:
...
string St1, St2;
...
ifstream In("Text.txt");
In >> St1 >> St2;
...
that St1 and St2 are initialized by reading from a file by ifstream() function. Now I want to write them in another file by fprintf() function.
fprintf("%s %s", St1, St2);
But I think fprint get char* not string.

Answer (score 1):

fprintf works analogous to printf, in the format specifier, you can mention as many %s as you want and give the corresponding number of string arguments. If you want a more detailed answer, please post your code.